# DBase in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, php-extension, pecl, dbase

How can I use DBase in CakePHP (v3.1)? I've already installed it with PECL (v5.1.1) and it works fine with plain php, but when I run dbase_create() in CakePHP it gives me an error:

***Call to undefined function App\Controller\dbase_open()***

I've included the extension in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

Comment: Does your controller use a custom namespace? If so, you might need to call `\dbase_open()` to tell PHP to use that function from the global namespace

Comment: No, i don't use any namespace for DBase.

Comment: No i mean your controller. According to the error message, you're in a `namespace App\Controller;`.

Comment: Sorry. Yeah cake automatically uses this namespace, but when I call it with \dbase_open() I'm getting also the error *Call to undefined function dbase_create()*. Any other ideas?

Comment: That last error is actually correct. That means PHP is looking for the function in the right place. Did you restart Apache after updating the php.ini files?

Comment: Yes, several times.

Comment: Interesting. If you call `phpinfo();`, is there anything dbase-related in the output?

Comment: When I call *phpinfo();* with a plain php file, dbase appears with version 5.1.1 - inside a CakePHP function there's no dbase at all. Thanks, this must be the error. CakePHP takes /etc/php5/cli/php.ini, but also but the extension in there...

Comment: the path to the used php.ini file should also be in the `phpinfo()` output

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Problem was that I only restarted the apache2 server. Had to restart my CakePHP Application too^^. Dumb mistake. Thanks, you helped me a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, let me summarize this debug session into an answer in case someone has a similar issue in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the debug steps taken to fix the problem:

1. The error message says the function `App\Controller\dbase_create()` does not exist. What we'd expect is the function `dbase_create()`, so the error message indicates PHP is looking in the wrong namespace. Changing the function call to `\dbase_create()` caused PHP to look in the global namespace.
2. PHP still gave an error message, this time saying the function `dbase_create()` does not exist. That at least indicates that PHP is now looking in the right place, but the function also doesn't exist in the global namespace.
3. The `php.ini` files were modified, but Apache loads all configuration files for its modules when it starts. To ensure changes are loaded, Apache needs to be restarted when the `php.ini` file is changed. Restart Apache to load the new version of the file.
4. After restarting Apache, the function still does not exist. Let's make sure the module is loaded properly. Call the `phpinfo()` function and check its output for anything related to DBase. This gave an interesting result: a separate PHP file with just `phpinfo()` indicated that DBase 5.1.1 was loaded, but calling `phpinfo()` from the CakePHP application did not output anything related to DBase.
5. CakePHP was running as its own server. Like Apache, the `php.ini` file is loaded when that server starts, so make sure to restart that server when the file changes. This fixed the issue, after restarting the CakePHP server the `dbase_create()` function was available.